# Monotouch: UILabel disappears after t seconds, how to

Tags: ios4, uikit, xamarin.ios, uilabel, fadeout

How is it possible to hide a UILabel after t seconds?

Could I use a background thread to do this?

Thank you in advance. Regards.

**EDIT**

For those interested in, following Luke advice:

```
var timer  = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), delegate{
 InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{

   UIView.BeginAnimations(null);
   UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.5);
   UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.None, labelToAnimateReference, true);
   UIView.SetAnimationDelegate(this);                           
   labelToAnimateReference.Alpha = 0.0f;
   UIView.CommitAnimations();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you'd be changing the UI, I would suggest using the Main Thread for the actual hiding of the label but yes this is possible:

```
NSTimer timer  = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(t, delegate{
    InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
        label.Alpha = 0.0f;
    });
});
```

(where t is an int for the time you'd like to hide the label!)

**EDIT**
If you want to fade the label out, then I'd suggest looking into `UIView` animations. 
[See reference docs here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). As of iOS 4.0+ it is suggested you use UIView animation blocks. 
To fit your example, the code would look like this:

```
NSTimer timer  = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(t, delegate{
    InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
        UIView.Animate(0.5f, delegate{
            label.Alpha = 0.0f;
        });
    });
});
```

The first value is the animation duration.
Just to note as well, where I'm using these `delegate{}` you can also do something like:

```
NSTimer timer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(t, FadeLabelOut());

// later on

void FadeLabelOut()
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Luke. It's that I was looking for. How could I add a Fade effect? Thank you.

Comment: Is it truly needed to InvokeOnMainThread? Right now I'm not using it to change UI Elements and it is working. Maybe the latest MonoTouch 5.2.12 is invoking the action on the UI Thread automatically.

Comment: @Jonas If you're not changing UI elements then I don't see why you'd need to invoke on the main thread. But bear in mind by not invoking on the main thread when changing UI elements, you can potentially hold up the rest of the app while your UI updates.

Comment: @Luke, from Xamarin support: "By default NSTimer uses the main run loop, so you do not need InvokeOnMainThread with NSTimer"